# What folder do I choose in the VMware kernel module updater?

Tags: kali-linux, vmware, linux-headers

When I run `vmware` in Kali Linux, this keeps showing up:

[image: Image of the VMware Kernel Module Updater]

I have kernel headers for version 6.3.0-kali1-amd64. What path do I use? When I choose a folder, this shows up:

[image: Error window]

I looked up the answers online and ran this script: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but it returns `E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-6.1.0-kali9-amd64` so that command won't work. I have updated and upgraded my Kali Linux operating, too.
Also I searched for linux header packages with the command `aptitude search linux-headers` and the only version was 6.3.0-kali1-amd64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have updated the system, but have not yet rebooted, so the system is still running on the old (pre-update) kernel. The package management system refuses to install an older `linux-headers` package because after just one boot you will be running a newer kernel and any modules built for the old one will be useless.

You probably already have installed the `linux-image-6.3.0-kali1-amd64_6.3.7-1kali1_amd64.deb` package that contains the kernel that matches your `linux-headers` package version, but it's not running yet.

Reboot, then verify that `uname -r` now outputs `6.3.0-kali1-amd64`, then try installing the VMware kernel module again.

Comment: You are right. `uname -r` outputs the outdated version so I will reboot my system.

Comment: It works after I rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```sh
sudo apt install linux-headers-amd64
```

Comment: I already have that installed.